# How to read different lines from a text file simultaneously

Tags: scala

I need to read a file line by line such that it reads the first line, does something with it, then takes the second line, does something with it and so on.

I know how to read a text file line by line:

```
for(line <- Source.fromFile("file.txt").getLines())
{
   insert(line) **Use the first line of the file in this function
   reverse(line) **Use the second line of the file in this function
}
```

in the insert function, first I want to use the first line of the file, and in the reverse function I want to use the second line, then in the second iteration of the loop, I want to use the 3rd line in the insert function and the 4th line in the reverse function and so on. How to do that?

EDIT: This is just an example. I want a general thing, like suppose if I want to use the first line, second line, third line and then iterate the for loop, how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `sliding` to group your lines into pairs of two.

```
for(pairs <- Source.fromFile("file.txt").getLines().sliding(2, 2)) {
    insert(pairs.head)
    reverse(pairs.last)
}
```

Obviously you'll need to handle the condition where you don't have a list of even length.

Comment: I want to make it a general case. Like this was just an example where I wanted first and second line and then loop iteration, suppose I want first, second and third line and then iteration, how to do that?

Comment: Figured it out! Thanks all :)

Answer (score 2):

Lots of clever solutions. Here's a simple one using zipWithIndex that handles even cases with an uneven number of lines.

```
for((line,index) <- Source.fromFile("file.txt").getLines().zipWithIndex)
{
  if (index % 2 == 0) insert(line) 
  else reverse(line)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One more approach, using `grouped`, which takes into account a (possibly) uneven number of lines,

```
Source.fromFile("file.txt")
  .getLines
  .grouped(2)
  .map { xs => (xs.head, xs.last.reverse) }
```

Note that `getLines` gives an iterator for fetching one line at a time, *sequentially*, then `grouped` gives yet another iterator with paired lines for *simultaneous* processing. This is in contrast with reading multiple lines of a file at the same time.

Comment: I want to make it a general case. Like this was just an example where I wanted first and second line and then loop iteration, suppose I want first, second and third line and then iteration, how to do that?

Comment: Increase `Int` value in `grouped`, also `xs.map{ /*awesome multiple lines processing */}`

Comment: Note, if the input doesn't have an even number of lines then this gives an exception on "xs.last". It's easy enough to fix up, but messy with n > 2. Also original question had imperative structure this has a more functional structure. That can be fixed by replacing ".map {...}" with ".foreach{ xs => {insert(xs.head), reverse(xs.last)} }". Then again, OP may have been asking for a functional transform. Hard to say.